# Pointer-to-Pointer Arithmetic: Assigning Values

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

My program is generating 4X4 matrices and a vector of constant terms that looks like this:

```
av + bx + cy + dz = e
a2_v + b2_x + c2_y + d2_z = e_2
a3_v + b3_x + c3_y + d3_z = e_3
a4_v + b4_x + c4_y + d4_z = e_4
```

In my `generateContentForSystems` method, I solve for the value of a, b, c, d, a2....etc.

I compile it with g++ because I have to use a C++ library in my `generateContentForSystems` method.

Though it correctly generates a new array of 5 integers, it somehow assigns the same array to `myArray[i]`, `myArray[i+1]` and `myArray[i+2]`.

```
int arrayIndexes = 0;
int ** myArray = (int **) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
    for (int b = 1; b < 10; b++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
           for(int e = 0; e <10; e++){
               myArray[arrayIndexes] = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
               myArray[arrayIndexes][0] = a;
               myArray[arrayIndexes][1] = b;
               myArray[arrayIndexes][2] = c;
               myArray[arrayIndexes][3] = d;
               myArray[arrayIndexes][4] = e;

               cout << "a: " << a << "b: " << b << "c: " << c << "d: " << d << "e" << e << endl;
               if (arrayIndexes >= 3) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayIndexes - 2; i++) {
                  cout << "row: " << myArray[i][0] <<myArray[i][1] << myArray[i][2] << myArray[i][3] << myArray[i][4] << endl;
                  generateContentForSystems(myArray[arrayIndexes], myArray[i], myArray[i+1], myArray[i+2]);
                }
              }
              ++arrayIndexes;
              myArray = (int **) realloc(myArray, (arrayIndexes + 1) * sizeof( * myArray));
            }
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Here is some output from when I run:

```
row: 11070
the value of A: 1 1 2 3
1 1 0 7
1 1 0 7
1 1 0 7
row: 11071
the value of A: 1 1 2 3
1 1 0 7
1 1 0 7
1 1 0 7
row: 11072
the value of A: 1 1 2 3
1 1 0 7
1 1 0 7
1 1 0 7
```

Given that this is C and we're dealing with (double) pointers, my hunch is that there is some undefined behavior somewhere in my code. Can you see why its not preserving values to the int pointer?

Comment: I think you should add more nested `for` loops to make your program better. And use `malloc` more too!

Comment: This is a very strange way to create an array. I've been staring at it for a minute and am still not sure either of the `malloc`s are correct. What's wrong with a nice `std::vector<int>` of size `x*y`? How do you intend to fit five values in a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: This code is not C — it contains `cout << …`.  That makes it C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is correct; more broadly, building it with a C++ compiler makes it C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and in that case, usage of `malloc()` should be discouraged.

Comment: for an array of 5 integers I would probably use a `std::vector<int>` and for a 4x4 matrix of integers I would probably use a `std::vector<int>`. Your `malloc` and the like is just asking for too much trouble

Comment: The statement `myArray[arrayIndexes] = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));` is going to be executed 100,000 times.  That doesn't look very plausibly what you intended.  You say you're creating 4x4 matrices, but there are a lot of 5's in the code.  'Tis puzzling.  You need to go back to the drawing board and restate to yourself what you are trying to do, and then you need to implement that instead of what you're showing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am generating 4X4 matrices and a vector of constant terms so that these 4X4 matrices can be solved. I will update my post with these details.

Comment: Well, you may be able to get your head around how your code with 5 levels of nested 0..9 loops generates 4x4 matrices, but I can't.  Let's just say "it isn't obvious how it is supposed to work from our side of the fence".  Presumably, since you're asking about it, it doesn't work. That makes it difficult for everyone. We have to try and guess what you're really trying to do, and then work out how what you've implemented relates to that. Are you trying to create 100,000 4x4 matrices?  — Good luck! (Oh, and the code you show doesn't produce the output you show! That's another way to confuse us!)

Comment: Are the `e` values in the set of equations all meant to be the same?  Or should they be subscripted?  Why the inconsistency of notation between the first line of equation and the remaining 3?  Consistency of presentation is valuable. (I'd use `a1_v + b1_x + c1_y + d1_z = e_1` for consistency with
`a2_v + b2_x + c2_y + d2_z = e_2`, though I'd probably use `e1` and `e2` for better consistency with `a2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
 int ** myArray = (int **) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
```

is very wrong. You are allocating memory equal to the size of one `int`, and after casting, you're storing that to (as) `int *`(s). Unless in the platform, `sizeof (int) == sizeof (int *)`, you're in deep trouble.

That said, you've allocated space for "only one" element, indexing more (from 1 to 9, or even 1 itself) into it, like

```
myArray[arrayIndexes] = .....
```

invokes the undefined behaviour, as you're accessing invalid memory.

Comment: I will definitely need to work on the line you mentioned. However, I indeed initially only allocate space for one element. But after I assign that pointer to the `int **`, I `realloc` and then enter the next iteration of the loop. Is this also undefined behavior?

Comment: @Matt: Allocating piecemeal is expensive — at least, more expensive than allocating everything all at once.  Minimize the number of allocations.  Do not grow an array by reallocating one more row each time.

Comment: so the correct thing to do is allocate for a set number from the beginning (`int ** myArray = (int **) malloc(10000 * 5 * sizeof(int *));`) and `return 0` once `arrayIndexes == 10000`